# Media queries issue with Twitter button

Tags: css, twitter, media-queries, twitter-follow

I have a Twitter follow button on the homepage of my personal website, but for some reason it is not responding to the media queries styles I have given to it. I am trying to hide the button on smaller screen sizes. Any ideas whats going wrong? Thanks in advance!

http://edharrisondesign.com/

Comment: In which browser? It is working fine for me in Chrome Beta.

Comment: In Chrome. It's working fine, but I want it to disappear when the screen size is reduced (and the thumbnails go down to two columns)

Comment: Aye, that is what I mean--the twitter button *does* disappear for me. Will check other browsers.

Comment: Just checked a few browsers and your right its working fine - just needed to clear my cache. Nice one!

Answer (score 0):

Just checked a few browsers and your right its working fine - just needed to clear my cache. Nice one!